# AngularJS FormController not being created

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I've run into a problem using forms in AngularJS.

So when I create a form on a page, like this:

```
<div class="dewps-shadow-box">
    <form role="form" name="myForm" ng-submit="processForm()"
        novalidate>
       ...
    </form>
</div>
```

The FormController myForm is created, as I can access it in the Javascript via $scope.myForm, and attributes such as $scope.myForm.$error.

In another part of the application, this same form is essentially duplicated:

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Forms" id="forms" class="myTab">
        <tabset>
            <tab heading="myForm Copy" id="myFormCopy" class="myTab">
                <form role="form" name="myFormCopy" ng-submit="processCopyForm()"
                    novalidate>
                   ...
                </form>
            </tab>
        </tabset>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

For this form, in the Javascript, there is no FormController "myFormCopy" created. As a result, I cannot access attributes such as $error.

I have tried using ngForm instead, but that hasn't worked. Looking at the documentation, it says a FormController is automatically created matching the name of the form, assuming it has one. Why isn't there one here. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you including this tabset inside of another form?

Comment: I'm not sure but i think your directive (ui bootstrap Tab) not support that, but when you clear your tab that work correctly.

Comment: @MichaelG, no this tabset is not inside of another form.

Maher, that's very possible. I don't necessarily have to have a solution here, but I wanted to check whether it was something preventable that I was doing.

Comment: Where is the part of code where you get an error when accessing `myFormCopy`?

Comment: It's particularly one line in my controller (it's coffeescript): "if $scope.personaForm.$error.pattern then return errorString"

However in the HTML as well I have buttons that do things like "myFormCopy.fieldOne.$setValidity..." and those also simply don't do anything.

Comment: @elykl33t please add the lines that actually throw error to the question.